# Change RGB value of pixel based on threshold OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I have an image in which pixels above a certain value I'd like to turn red, and pixels below a certain value I'd like to turn blue.

So far, I can get a matrix of red pixels, and a matrix of blue pixels by using thresholding, and bitwise operators to set the pixel value:

```
cvtColor(displayImage, displayImage, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

threshold(displayImage, highThresh, highThreshVal, 255, 0);
highThresh = highThresh & Scalar(0, 0, 255); // Turn it red

threshold(displayImage, lowThresh, lowThreshVal, 255, 1);
lowThresh = lowThresh & Scalar(255, 0, 0); // Turn it blue

displayImage = lowThresh + highThresh;
```

When I display the `displayImage`, I see almost exactly what I want.  It's an image where all the pixels below `lowThreshVal` are blue, and all pixels above `highThreshVal` are red.  However, the pixels that are in between these values are all set to 0.  Whereas, I would like to show the original image overlayed with the blue and red images.  I'm not sure how to do this, or if I'm taking the best approach.

I know I can't add the images because I want to make sure every pixel above the threshold is pure red, not a mix of red and the original image, this yields pink-ish pixels instead of bright red pixels, which defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to build.  But as of right now, I'm kind of stuck on what to do.

Comment: Use `lowThresh` and `highThresh` as a mask with [`cv::Mat::setTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-setto)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked.

```
cvtColor(displayImage, displayImage, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
origImage = displayImage.clone();

threshold(origImage, highThresh, highThreshVal, 255, 0); // Binary thresholding
cvtColor(highThresh, highThresh, CV_BGR2GRAY);
displayImage.setTo(Scalar(0, 0, 255), highThresh);

threshold(origImage, lowThresh, lowThreshVal, 255, 1); // Binary thresholding
cvtColor(lowThresh, lowThresh, CV_BGR2GRAY);
displayImage.setTo(Scalar(255, 0, 0), lowThresh);
```